# To stop the for loop from executing DownloadWebpage task when certain conditions are met

Tags: android

I am downloading certain data's from web as under:

```
   private void marketTableShow() throws IOException {
       for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
          String stri = String.valueOf(i);
          String stringUrl = ""http://live-nse.herokuapp.com/?symbol="+ stri
          new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);

        mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                String strmsg = msg.toString();
                if (strmsg.contains("[]")) {
                     //to stop the loop
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

private class DownloadWebpageTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        for (String url : urls) {
            try {
                strcontent = downloadUrl(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Dialog(e);
            }
        }
        return strcontent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
        System.out.println(results);
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.obj = results;
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Now I want that when certain conditions namely

```
if (strmsg.contains("[]")) {
     ***//to stop the loop***
}
```

is met than no more downloading and after which I should exit the for loop.It is not taking break command at this point.What can be the possible way.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer would be to use abreak or return depending on how far you need to exit the loop. 
A more 'elegant' way would be to throw an exception : it would also enable you to detect that you have left the loop because you have met your condition.
Don't forget to clean up (close streams, etc...) Before you leave.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` you are trying to exit is going to finish long before the `Handler` fires, because you start all the `AsyncTasks` at the same time. Roughly...They'll all start within a millisecond of one another. The `Handler` won't fire for several milliseconds.

To stop them midcourse, you're going to need some trickier coding. Perhaps buffering the downloads and checking a `WeakReference` to see if the content is still needed between buffer loads.